MongooseError Db while setting up database
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.createClient (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\BookStore\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:219:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\BookStore\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:823:34)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\BookStore\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\mongoose.js:448:15)
    at conn (file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/BookStore/backend/connection/conn.js:7:20)
    at file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/BookStore/backend/app.js:14:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)
Server is running on port 8080

I want to setup my database:

Hello! Could you please include the JavaScript code that calls mongoose.connect() (make sure to remove the database key provided to you by MongoDB)?

As the error message states, you need to make sure that you pass a string of the database URI to mongoose.connect(). You can obtain the database URI by going to your MongoDB cluster on the MongoDB website and clicking Connect. The URI should start with this:
mongodb+srv://<db_username>:<db_password>@<cluster_name>...

In your call to mongoose.connect(), include the URI like so:
await mongoose.connect('<your database URI here>');

You can also take a look at:

Mongoose documentation on connections
Mozilla tutorial on connecting to MongoDB with mongoose

